# @try @catch block working on iOS 6 but not on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, try-catch

I have a tableview with 2 subviews in cell (small thumbnail with label) and I want to hide the second subview if there is nothing to load in it (when only first subview has the image and title to load).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *reuse = @"reuse";
    ContentTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuse];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[Utils buildNibNameFromPrefix:@"ContentTableViewCell"] owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    cell.cellIndex = indexPath.row;

    NSUInteger selectedIndex = [Utils getIndexForContentTitle:[Utils getContentBookmark]];
    NSUInteger titleIndex = indexPath.row * self.noOfContentPerCell;
    NSUInteger cellIndex = NSNotFound;
    for (int i = 0; i < self.noOfContentPerCell; i++) {
        @try {
            if (titleIndex == selectedIndex) {
                cellIndex = i;
            }

            NSArray *content;
            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"unlock"] == NO) {
                content = CONTENT_INDEXS;
            }
            else {
                content = CONTENT_INDEXS_UNLOCKED;
            }

            NSString *title = [content objectAtIndex:titleIndex];
            [cell setTitle:title forContentAtIndex:i];

            NSString *thumbnail;

            if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )
            {
                thumbnail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-iphone-thumbnail.jpg", title];
            }
            else
            {
                thumbnail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-ipad-thumbnail.jpg", title];
            }

            [cell setImageNamed:thumbnail atIndex:i];

            [cell showContainerAtIndex:i];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            [cell hideContainerAtIndex:i];
        }
        titleIndex++;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

It works on iOS 6, if there is no content to load, @catch hides this subview, but on iOS 5 crash occurs at:

```
NSString *title = [content objectAtIndex:titleIndex];
```

Comment: Why do you have a try-catch block? What code can throw an exception? Why not simply check the titleIndex against the content length?

Comment: You say a "crash occurs".  Is it an exception or what?  What is the exact message?  Generally a storage error will just yank the rug, without generating an exception.

Comment: There is no object in the index of the array, that's why it crashes

Comment: What is the precise message??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems silly.
- I usually hate `Try/Catch` unless there is no other way.
- Why not just check to see if the `index` exists on that collection.
- In other words, instead of seeing if there will be an `error`, check the **condition** that would cause the `error` and deal with that.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will do that, but just out of curiosity, why shouldn't I use exception handling for these kind of cases? Also, I am interested in why this code works on iOS 6 ant not on iOS 5?

Comment: Try/Catch is a lazy way to code IMO.  Do the work and code properly and 99% of the time you won't need to use Try/Catch.  This is used pervasively in the .NET world because of lazy programmers.  Heck most of the time the only thing the catch block does is either log an exception or do nothing.  At least that has been my experience.  As to why it isn't working on iOS 5, I would bet something changed with the way a nil is passed back from that objectAtIndex method.  Have you checked the value of that NSString object to see what value it has on iOS6 where you would see the error on iOS5?

Comment: @1337code - One problem is that only a relatively small subset of possible errors result in an exception.  Others just take Unix-style traps.

Comment: Try/catch has a lot of overhead too, it's a higher level version of setjmp/longjmp.

Comment: @1337 You're essentially using Try/Catch in place of a single `if` statement; that's pretty inefficient. Just check to make sure the index is not beyond the bounds of the array before you use it to access an object. Using Try/Catch for this is like littering your C code with `GOTO` statements to replace `break` and `else`. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense. If you had used an `if` statement, you probably wouldn't even be having this problem right now.